# docker how to handle permissions for jupyter notebook - 3 approaches that do not work

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

What is the best practice for handling uid/gid and permissions with jupyter notebooks in docker?

1. When one of the jupyter+python Dockerfiles in [jupyter/docker-stack](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/scipy-notebook) is run, a notebook gets saved with uid/gid 1000:100.  This will fail if a mounted host folder is not writable by "other", which is an ugly approach.
2. The notebook image can be run specifying the NB_UID and NB_GID, like this:

   ```
    docker run -p 8888:8888 -it --rm \
      -e NB_UID=$(id -u) \
      -e NB_GID=$(id -g) \
      -e GRANT_SUDO=yes \
      --user root \
      --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/home/jovyan/work \
      myimage
   ```

   In this case, the uid/gid of joyvan in the container match **my** uid/gid, so there is no permissions problem writing to a mounted folder. However, now jovyan (the container user) cannot access `/opt/conda`, which is owned by 1000:100 and is not readable by other.  So all the add-on packages cannot be loaded!
3. We could also run docker build with `--build-arg myuid=$(id -u) --build-arg mygid=$(id -g)`

   I believe this would result in both `/home/jovyan` and `/opt/conda` being owned by the same uid:gid as me, everything good. However, the resulting image can be used *only* by me.  If I give it to my collaborators (who has a different UID), it will not work.

So it seems that every possibility is blocked or a poor choice. File permissions in docker are difficult.

Can anyone share the best approach for this problem?

Comment: You're mixing build-time with run-time, so by setting the `NB_UID` and `NB_GID` environment variables at run time (with the `docker run`) you're not changing the permissions that have been set during the build-time. Are the problems with the permissions happening on build time? In that case you don't need `RUN sudo` you can just say `USER root` then `RUN chown -R ...` and then `USER $NB_UID` again. If you need sudo during run time to work you could add the user to the sudoers and it'll work as well.

Comment: you are right, that is part of my confusion.  I am going to edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 10):

The best practise with Jupyter Notebook is to use your own user id and group id so the new files you create will have correct ownership. Then use `--group-add users` to add yourself to **users** group to get access to the required folders (e.g. /opt/conda).

The full command would be:

`docker run -it --rm --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --group-add users -v "$(pwd)":/home/jovyan -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and found a good solution which is referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879364/docker-copy-and-change-owner).

```
COPY --chown=1000:100 hostfolder/* /home/$NB_USER/work/
```

*Note that environment or argument expansion in command options is not implemented yet, thus following line would cause build error `failed to build: unable to convert uid/gid chown string to host mapping: can't find uid for user $NB_UID: no such user: $NB_UID`*

```
# COPY --chown=$NB_USER:$NB_GID hostfolder/* /home/$NB_USER/work/
```

Therefore, need to hard code the user(jovyan) and group name(users) or id(1000:100).